# 1120: Access of undefined property loader

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, compiler-errors

I have this code I'm trying to load a file .txt in my FLEX project. But something weird is happening, it's giving me this error, but the main point is... I ran this code in Flash using Dynamic text instead TextArea... and it runs perfectly, I'm starting to think that I have some problem with my FLEX software... Does somebody could help me, please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
 <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import flash.events.*;
   import flash.net.*;

   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

   loader.load(new URLRequest("external.txt"));
   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

   function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    text1.text = e.target.data;
   }
  ]]>
 </mx:Script>

 <mx:TextArea id="text1" x="209" y="275" width="226.66666" height="208.2738"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Severity and Description Path Resource Location Creation Time Id
1120: Access of undefined property loader. IVSketch/src IVSketch.mxml line 10 1261589517158 451
1120: Access of undefined property loader. IVSketch/src IVSketch.mxml line 11 1261589517159 452
1120: Access of undefined property onComplete. IVSketch/src IVSketch.mxml line 11 1261589517159 453

Comment: are these lines of code inside a function?

Comment: Is this a runtime error or does it come from the compiler? Which lines do the errors point to? I'm puzzled as why it is trying to treat onComplete as a property instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function load() : void {
  var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
  loader.load(new URLRequest("external.txt")); 
}

private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
  text1.text = URLLoader(e.target).data; 
}
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using it right. Your code should look like:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
```